# mvc validationMessage is not working while its in IEnumerable<T>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-validation

I have a class :

```
public class Cust
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="NameField Req")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I use this class :

```
public class CustModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Cust> CustList { get; set; }
}
```

**.Cshtml**

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.CustModel

  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.CustList)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(val => val.CustList)
```

When I hit on Submit button `if (ModelState.IsValid){}` is working but why my error message is not displayed ?

Comment: have you included required js for validation?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to re-produce your code, assuming your view:

**Please, pay attention to the for loop**:

```
@model MVC_SteckOverflow.Models.ViewModels.CustModel
@using MVC_SteckOverflow.Models.ViewModels

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ValidateIenumerable";
}

<style>
    .field-validation-error {
        color:#F00;
    }
    .input-validation-error {
        border: 1px solid red;
        background-color: #f9e2e2b3;
    }
</style>

<h2>ValidateIenumerable</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>CustModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @for (int i = 0; i != Model.CustList.Count(); i++)
            {
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.CustList.ToList()[i].Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CustList.ToList()[i].Name)
            }


            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

according to the following actions in the Controller:

```
    public ActionResult ValidateIenumerable()
    {
        CustModel custModel = new CustModel {
            CustList = new List<Cust> {
                new Cust{ Name = "A"},
                new Cust{ Name = "B"},
                new Cust{ Name = "C"},
            },
        };
        return View(custModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ValidateIenumerable(CustModel custModel)
    {

        return View(custModel);
    }
```

The code above, is tested, built and run successfully.
[image]

Hope this helped ... :)

Comment: if i wana to add and remove dynamically

Comment: Please explain more. The code above already works with dynamic lists according to the for loop inside cshtml: `@for (int i = 0; i != Model.CustList.Count(); i++)`

Comment: So you can create any `CustModel` dynamically in your controller as you wish.